# TypeError: (0 , _dataActions.loginUser) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

This is my Redux async action for user login

```
export const loginUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
  return axios
    .post('/login', userData)
    .then((res) => {
      setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);
      dispatch(getUserData());
      dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
      history.push('/');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
};

export const getUserData = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_USER });
    // send get request, if response exist, then dispatch SET_USER action
    return axios
    .get('/user')
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_USER,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

I'm testing that when `loginUser` is called, it will dispatch `LOADING_UI`, along with `LOADING_USER` and `SET_USER` with expected payload, then `CLEAR_ERRORS`

```
describe('dataActions', () => {
    const middlewares = [thunk];
    const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

    beforeEach(() => {
        moxios.install();
    });

    it('should dispatch an action to login a user', () => {
        moxios.wait(() => {
            const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
            request.respondWith({
                status: 200
            });
        });

        const expectedActions = [
            { type: LOADING_UI },
            { type: LOADING_USER },
            { type: SET_USER },
            { type: CLEAR_ERRORS }
        ]

        const store = mockStore({ userData: {}, history: {} })

        return store.dispatch(loginUser()).then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        moxios.uninstall();
    })
})
```

However, I'm receiving `TypeError: (0 , _dataActions.loginUser) is not a function`. The error points to this line of code `return store.dispatch(loginUser()).then(() => {`. I'm not familiar with this error so any help is appreciated.

Also, is this the suggested logic to test for the user login action? Or should I test for something different altogether? Thank you.

Comment: try passing data to loginUser function

Comment: @user2222 Sorry, it didn't work. I receive `ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: can i know what data you put?

Comment: @user2222 Sure, I passed `data` as an argument to the `loginUser` function when dispatching to the `store` in my test. Here is the code `return store.dispatch(loginUser(data)).then(() => {expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);});`

Comment: when i tell you to pass data, i mean a valid args for loginUser function, which means a userdata and history that you need to declare beforehand.

Comment: @user2222 apologies, i misunderstood. i've then declared userData and history but still receive the same error. `const store = mockStore({ userData: {}, history: {} })`